# Integration of one-form

Tags: proof-verification, manifolds, differential-forms, stokes-theorem, manifolds-with-boundary

I am trying to compute

$$\int_C i^*\eta$$

$\eta=(x^2+y^2)dz$ and $C=\{(x,y,-1): x^2+y^2=1\}$ and $i$ is the inclusion map

This is what I did
$$\int_{-1}^{-1}(x^2+y^2) dz=0 $$
Is this correct?

Comment: The answer is right, but how did you justify the answer? It's not so clear from what you wrote.

Comment: @ziggurism which step should I expand on? I just integrated the one-form over $C$.

Comment: the definition of the integral of a differential form is in terms of local charts. You did not use that here. So what method are you using to "just integrate the one-form"? Can you perform integrals just by looking at them?

Comment: @ziggurism Then I fear I messed up. The chart in question is $h(a,b)=(\sin a, \cos a, -b-1)$ with $U_1=\{-\pi \leq a \leq \pi,  -1 < b \leq 0   \}$ and $U_2=\{0 \leq a \leq 2\pi,  -1 < b \leq 0   \}$. How can I apply this to do it correctly?

Comment: Well you integrate 1-forms along 1-manifolds, and you appear to be parametrizing a 2-manifold...

Comment: We don’t even have to go into integration with the chart. In this case, the form is identically zero over C. Compute the pullback of $\eta$ to see that.

Comment: @ziggurism Yes, $C$ is the boundary of my 2-manifold (finite cylinder) and I am trying to calculate a two form over this 2-manifold and it reduces to the problem here.

Comment: @PMM $C$ is a circle, not a cylinder...

Comment: @ziggurism Yes, C is a circle, which is the boundary of a finite cylinder ($1\leq z \leq 0$). In the original problem I need to integrate a two-form over the cylinder, and by Stokes Theorem it can be reduced to the problem above, integrating a one-form over C, the boundary, of the cylinder.

Comment: @PMM ok, if you want to integrate over the cylinder, you should parametrize the cylinder. But the question posted above is about integrating over the circle. So you should parametrize the circle. With is a 1-manifold. (BTW I guess the boundary of a cylinder should be _two_ circles, but ok close enough)

Comment: @Mathemagical $i*\eta = 1dz$. This is what I get?

Comment: no, $i^*\eta=0.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circle $C=\{(x,y,-1)\colon x^2+y^2=1\}$ admits a parametrization by $(x,y,z)=(\cos t,\sin t,-1),$ for $0\leq t\leq 2\pi.$ Therefore if $$\eta=(x^2+y^2)\,dz$$ we compute 
$$i^*\eta=(\cos^2t+\sin^2t)\,d(-1)=0.$$

Hence $$\int_0^{2\pi} i^*\eta = 0.$$

Intuitively, a 1-form with only a $dz$ component is a 1-form which measures only $z$-components of directional derivatives. So it vanishes along any curve with constant $z$-component.

Comment: Thanks 1 see where I went wrong, now

Comment: Btw, Congrats on hitting the 10k rep, @ziggurism

Comment: @Mathemagical thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If $c:I \to C$ is given by $c(t)=(\cos 2\pi t,\sin 2\pi t, -1)$ where $I=[0,1]$.

Then your integral is $\int_I (i \circ c)^*\eta$

For the vector $\mathbf{v}$ in the 1-D tangent space of I, 
$$(i \circ c)^* \eta(\mathbf{v})=\eta((i \circ c)_*(\mathbf{v})=(x^2+y^2)dz( -2 \pi v \sin 2 \pi t, 2 \pi v \cos 2\pi t, 0)=0$$

Comment: If you can already see how the tangent vectors of C end up under the inclusion map, you don’t have to go to $I$ to see that it is zero.

Comment: Thanks for spelling it out. Makes sense now.